# given a list of record id to be retain. What is the best way to delete non-members?

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I have a list of record id for those records to be retained. What is the best way to delete all records not in the set ? I am using MySQL and ADO.NET with C#. I want to minimize time to complete all delete's.

Comment: `NOT IN` is not good enough for you?

Comment: the retention list has about 100000 id . I tried ADO.NET deleting one-by-one and a C# dictionary for the 100000 id. It can complete in about  10 minutes. But I am not sure if there are best practices for large number deletion.  I have not tried NOT IN..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is where do you have those ids? Are they in another table? Are they in a file?

If you only have a few ids

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2, 7, 8, 10);
```

If you take the ids from a table

```
DELETE foo.* FROM foo LEFT JOIN foo_bar ON foo.id = foo_bar.foo_id WHERE foo_bar.foo_id IS NULL;
```

If you have the ids in a file (one id per line)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo_keep (id INT, PRIMARY KEY (id));
LOAD DATE INFILE '/tmp/myids.list' INTO foo_keep;
DELETE foo.* FROM foo LEFT JOIN foo_keep ON foo.id = foo_keep.id WHERE foo_keep.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: JOIN would be the fastest method. Also, if the records that you want to keep are few compared to the entire table, maybe you should consider the opposite option, creating a temporary table with those records and replacing the existent one, instead of deleting a large number of records.